# Cannot resolve constructor ArrayAdapter in onPostExecute in AsyncTask

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter

I know this may sound like a repeated question but i have tried all of the solutions nothing works.It displays the error "Cannot resolve constructor ArrayAdapter" I have listview in Mainactivity which i have passed to second activity where i am searching a remote db and displaying results in listview.
Take a look..Thank You..
     this is mainactivity:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity
implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
private EditText location;
private TextView result ;
ListView lv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    location = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.lv );
 }
 public void search(View view){
    String slocation = location.getText().toString();
    new SearchActivity(this,lv,1).execute(slocation);
}
```

SearchActivity

```
public class SearchActivity extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String[]>{
private Context context;
private int byGetOrPost = 0;
private TextView sresult;
ListView lv1;
JSONArray garages;
String[] names;

public SearchActivity(Context context,ListView lv1,int flag) {
    this.context = context;
    byGetOrPost = flag;
    this.lv1 = lv1;
}

protected void onPreExecute(){

}

@Override
protected String[] doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        try{
            String location = (String)arg0[0];

            String link="http://garagekhojo.in/androidtest.php";
            String data  = URLEncoder.encode("location", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(location, "UTF-8");

            URL url = new URL(link);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

            wr.write( data );
            wr.flush();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            // Read Server Response
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line);
                break;
            }

            String newsb = sb.toString();
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(newsb) ;
            garages = jo.getJSONArray("garages");
            for (int i = 0; i < garages.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = garages.getJSONObject(i);

                names[i] = c.getString("name");
            }
            return names;


        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return null;
        }

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String[] names){
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.class,names);
    lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

Comment: try this may it will help you use context instead of this.
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.class,names);

Comment: also post your ArrayAdapter class code please.

Comment: @Nowshad ArrayAdapter is predefined class in android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit your SearchActivity.java. First Name it as SearchAsyncTask. You haven't initialize the name[] string array that't why it is throwing you null pointer exception.

Here is the code of SearchAsyncTask.java

```
public class SearchAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String[]>{
private Context context;
private int byGetOrPost = 0;
private TextView sresult;
ListView lv1;
JSONArray garages;

public SearchActivity(Context context,ListView lv1,int flag) {
   this.context = context;
   byGetOrPost = flag;
   this.lv1 = lv1;
}

protected void onPreExecute(){

}

@Override
protected String[] doInBackground(String... arg0) {
     try{
        String location = (String)arg0[0];

        String link="http://garagekhojo.in/androidtest.php";
        String data  = URLEncoder.encode("location", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(location, "UTF-8");

        URL url = new URL(link);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

        wr.write( data );
        wr.flush();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        // Read Server Response
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line);
            break;
        }

        String newsb = sb.toString();
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(newsb) ;
        garages = jo.getJSONArray("garages");
        String[] names = new String[garages.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < garages.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = garages.getJSONObject(i);
            names[i] = c.getString("name");
        }
        return names;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String[] names){
    if(names!=null){
       ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
       adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.class,names);
       lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

You should apply null check too as in case of exception you are returning null as value. so again if any exception will occur so it will get crashed. Also there is no need to define global variable String[] names as you are not using that variable. I have edited the class and name of the class too. Please check.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir !! I appreciate your effort and demise my stupidness.

Comment: No worries. Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

Please pass the Context of activity to the async task and use in place of this

```
 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.class,names);
```

where context is from   `this.context = context;`

and never use Activity as suffix  for AsyncTask (bad practice) 
(Instead of SearchActivity use SearchAsyncTask)

Comment: Allows me to build but "unfortunately stopped working"  on running.